# Mongodb group by element inside json structure

Tags: json, mongodb, scala

I'm looking for a database that fits my needs, and i was doing tests with mongodb, but i don't know if i will be able to do this what i want.

I have a json document like this on my mongodb collection:

```
{
    "gameId": 1,
    "gameDuration": 1234,
    "teams": [{
        "teamId": 1,
        "win": true
    }, {
        "teamId": 2,
        "win": false
    }],
    "players": [{
        "playerId": 1,
        "teamId": 1,
        "age": 32
    }, {
        "playerId": 2,
        "teamId": 2,
        "age": 52
    }]
}
```

So i have a collection of games that look like this.
I want to be able to query the most common age of players, or get the ages sorted. I don't care if a player is in 2 different games, i just want the most common age of all games independent of the player and the team.

So if i have 4 games:

```
[{
        "gameId": 1,
        "gameDuration": 1234,
        "teams": [{
            "teamId": 1,
            "win": true
        }, {
            "teamId": 2,
            "win": false
        }],
        "players": [{
            "playerId": 1,
            "teamId": 1,
            "years": 32
        }, {
            "playerId": 2,
            "teamId": 2,
            "years": 52
        }]
    },
    {
        "gameId": 2,
        "gameDuration": 1234,
        "teams": [{
            "teamId": 1,
            "win": true
        }, {
            "teamId": 2,
            "win": false
        }],
        "players": [{
            "playerId": 1,
            "teamId": 1,
            "years": 25
        }, {
            "playerId": 2,
            "teamId": 2,
            "years": 23
        }]
    },
    {
        "gameId": 3,
        "gameDuration": 1234,
        "teams": [{
            "teamId": 1,
            "win": true
        }, {
            "teamId": 2,
            "win": false
        }],
        "players": [{
            "playerId": 1,
            "teamId": 1,
            "years": 32
        }, {
            "playerId": 2,
            "teamId": 2,
            "years": 23
        }]
    },
    {
        "gameId": 4,
        "gameDuration": 1234,
        "teams": [{
            "teamId": 1,
            "win": true
        }, {
            "teamId": 2,
            "win": false
        }],
        "players": [{
            "playerId": 1,
            "teamId": 1,
            "years": 32
        }, {
            "playerId": 2,
            "teamId": 2,
            "years": 27
        }]
    }
]
```

The result of sorted ages should be: `[32, 23, 52, 25, 27]` Or the most common age should be `32`
Or it will be great to get the count of each age. 
`[{"32": 3}, {"23": 2}, {"25": 1}, {"27": 1}]`

I have search but can't find a way to do this query.
I have to say that this database will have a lot of games, millions, so i want to know how can a query to do this will affect to the performance. I don't want a 200ms query, but i also don't want a 1h query.

I am using the [mongodb-scala-conector](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-scala-driver) to do the query's, but it can be in any language and i can then try to parse to my needs.

I looked to other databases to do this, but as mongodb let me insert the json directly, it was my first option. But if it don't fits my needs, i also looked for [Apache Cassandra](http://cassandra.apache.org/), and if that don't fit i will go for a relational db, parsing the json to defined tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you check if the following aggregation serves what you need:

```
db.games.aggregate([{$unwind:"$players"}, {$group:{_id:"$players.years", count:{$sum:1}}}, {$sort:{count:-1}}])
```

Or:

```
db.games.aggregate([{$unwind:"$players"}, {$group:{_id:"$players.years", count:{$sum:1}}}, {$sort:{count:-1}}, {$limit:1}])
```